# Missing bottom level item when a node is linked to two menu objects

Tags: 8, navigation

I have been trying to create a custom menu block which shows a number of menu items with images on the current level.

I am having an issue where the active trail array doesn't return an menu item for the active node on level 4 of my menu. Here is an example of how I get the active trail:

```
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_parent_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_name = 'main';

// Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

foreach($parameters->activeTrail as $active_menu_link) {
  if($active_menu_link !== '') {
    $active_menu_id = explode(':', $active_menu_link);
    $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid($active_menu_id[0], $active_menu_id[1]);

    kint($entity->getTitle());
  }
}
```

It seems that the issue is mostly related to the fact that the same node is linked to both a child menu item and a parent menu item. If I remove this then the function works as expected. This is the my menu structure.

[image: Menu Structure for Site]

The two menu items highlighted in red are both linked to the same node since I want it to act as an overview page for the category. It could be that theres something else I can do to structure the menu differently. I am open to any alternatives on how I can get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by manipulating the tree object manually further down my module. I checked if the url of the parent object matched any of the child objects via a loop.

```
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_parent_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_name = 'main';

// Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

// Setup current link
$currentLinkId = reset($parameters->activeTrail);
$parameters->setRoot($currentLinkId);

// Load the tree based on this set of parameters.
$tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

// Get the parent of current menu so we can use its
// children as the links
$parameters->setRoot(reset($tree)->link->getParent());
$tree = $menu_parent_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

// Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
$manipulators = array(
  // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
  // Use the default sorting of menu links.
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
);
$tree = $menu_parent_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

foreach($tree as $key => $menu_item) {
  // Check if the link is the current page?
  $current_internal_path = $menu_item->link->getUrlObject()->toString();
  foreach($menu_item->subtree as $sub_key => $sub_link) {
    $sub_internal_path = $sub_link->link->getUrlObject()->toString();

    if($current_internal_path == $sub_internal_path) {
      unset($tree[$key]->subtree[$sub_key]);
    }

    // Check if we have another sub tree (we are not the parent). This can happen when a parent
    // link is attached to the same node as a child one.
    if($sub_link->subtree && count($sub_link->subtree)) {
      $lower_level_links = $sub_link->subtree;

      foreach($lower_level_links as $lower_link_key => $lower_level_link) {
        $lower_level_url = $lower_level_link->link->getUrlObject()->toString();
        if($sub_internal_path == $lower_level_url) {
          // Set the active menu level as this.
          $tree = array($sub_link);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Build up our menu
$menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);
```

This is perhaps not the cleanest solution with a lot of extra processing required but seems to work in this instance.